# Find the maximum similar substring in another string

Tags: algorithm

I am being given two strings, n1 and n2. Along with these, I am being provided with a number, K.

Now I need to find three numbers - i,j,l such that: 
  The substring starting at index i in n1, of length l, has atmost K mismatches with the substring of length l at index j of n2. And this is the maximum substring possible with K dissimilarity.

An example should make it clear:
n1 = tabriz
n2 = torino
K  = 2
then the output should be:
i = 2
j = 1
l = 4
[ since "briz" and "orin" have 2 dissimilarity]

Current approach: For each subsequence of n1, I am trying to find the maximum common subsequence in n2(with atmost K mismatches).  Anyone with a better approach to solve this more efficiently?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, it seems to me to be a variant of approximate string matching ( See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching ).

Comment: Possibly a combination of approximate string matching and finding the longest common substring: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: From hackerrank: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/substring-diff

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple bruteforce. It calculates the length for every possible pair of i and j. The complexity is O(n1.length * n2.length * min(n1.length, n2.length)). When both strings are of length n this is **O(n<sup>3</sup>)**.

```java
for (i = 0; i < n1.length; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n2.length; j++)
    {
        errors = 0
        len = 0

        while (errors <= k && i+len < n1.length && j+len < n2.length)
        {
             if (n1[i+len] != n2[j+len]) errors++
             if (errors <= k) len++
        }

        if (len > best) update best
    }
}
```

Here is a more efficient solution that goes through all the possible offsets between i and j, sets up a substring with k errors at that offset, then shifts the substring along (keeping it with exactly k errors) and observes the length at each point. The complexity is O((n1.length + n2.length) * min(n1.length, n2.length)). When both strings are of length n this is **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

```java
for (offset = -n1.length; offset < n2.length; offset++)
{
    // j is equal to (i + offset)

    start = (offset > 0) ? 0 : -offset
    stop = min(n1.length, n2.length - offset)

    errors = 0
    e = start // e is one past the end of the sequence, so l = e - i

    for (i = start; i < stop; i++)
    {
        // move the end of the substring to maintain exactly k errors
        while (e < stop && (errors < k || n1[e] == n2[e+offset]))
        {
            if (n1[e] != n2[e+offset]) errors++
            e++
        }

        if (e - i > best) update best

        if (n1[i] != n2[i+offset]) errors--
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with dynamic programming like LCS,

common(i,j,l,k) = maximum substring strats at i in s1, has length l, and at most k mismatch (for all i<=n,j<=n,l<=n,k<=K)
first you should calculate common(i,j,l,0) which is trivial.

for k>0:

> for all 1≤f≤k-1 && k-f≤t≤l-1:
>
> ## if str1[i+l-t] != str2[j+l-t]
>
> ```
>  common(i,j,l,k) = maximum{common(i,j,l-t-1,k-f) + common(i,j,t,f-1)} 
> else
>   common(i,j,l,k) = maximum{common(i,j,l-t,k-f) + common(i,j,t,f)}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It's guaranteed that there is a simple solution?, what happens in this case:

n1=qertyq

n2=quertac

K=2

there will be multiple solutions for the algorithm
0,0,6

1,1,5

2,2,4

3,3,3

2,2,2

if you're guaranteed that there's only one solution to the problem I think Saeed is right, you have to use dynamic programming to solve it